# Does Arquilian Warp support Unit Testing JSF 1.2

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, jsf-1.2, jboss-arquillian, jsfunit

This is my first shot at unit testing a **JSF 1.2** + **RichFaces 3.3.3** application; going through available frameworks, I found out about **JSFUnit** which *should* work with this JSF version, but later on discovered that this project is now discontinued and replaced with **Arquilian Warp** (which works with other related components).

However, due lack of documentation, I couldn't figure out if **Arquilian Warp** supports **JSF 1.2**; so can anyone answer, can I go ahead with it, or is **JSFUnit** my only option for the moment ?

Comment: I don't know of anything that would stop it from working, have you tried?

Comment: Nope, do you suggest I should ? That would be wonderful, instead of learning to use JSFUnit for my older project, and Arquillian Warp for the newer one.

Comment: Yeah, try it. If it doesn't work create some tickets and maybe we can get it working for jsf 1.2

Comment: I like having the possibility :) It has been at least 4 years of no activity on this progress, I'll give it a try anyhow since it's worth it.. but still it's very weird how this thing is not clear.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it works out of the box yet, seeing this:
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContextWrapper

Comment: Well, you have your answer now :) create a JIRA ticket and see what happens from there.

Comment: Filed ticket [ARQ-2015](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-2015), a real disappointment..

Comment: Sorry, JSF 1.2 is 10 years old, that's really a long time for things to be supported. You may simply be stuck with JSFUnit or similar until you're able to upgrade to a more current version of JSF.

Comment: I don't mind that, if there was a single working example for JSFUnit that would run Tomcat. So far, I've spent many hours with the available projects and running into missing dependencies or else runtime issues due to incompatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Readme on Github](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-warp), JSF2 is mentioned to be supported, which leads me to believe that *Arquillian Warp* does **not** work with *JSF 1.2*.